# jquery add class to TR from th label for tag

Tags: jquery

I need to dynamically add a class equal to the label tags for value to the parent tr... here is the code I have for the HTML

```
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">
    <label for="field[85]" id="rahil">File Upload</label>
    </th>
<td style="background:#eee;border:1px solid #ddd"><a href="" target="_blank">Info here</a></td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery I'm trying is as follows:

```
$("tr th label").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("for");        
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass(id);
});
```

The resulting code should be something like:

```
<tr valign="top" class="field85">
<th scope="row">
    <label for="field[85]" id="rahil">File Upload</label>
    </th>
<td style="background:#eee;border:1px solid #ddd"><a href="" target="_blank">Info here</a></td>
</tr>
```

Basically, want to grab the labels for value, add it as a class to the parent tr and remove the brackets `[]`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add .replace

```
var id = $(this).attr("for").replace(/(\[|\])/g,''); 
                                        ^  ^   = ^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eh977/1/

replace method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the class is added, but with the brackets, so just replace them with nothing :

```
$("tr th label").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("for").replace(/(\[|\])/g,'');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass(id);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yNVBe/)